# Using fill(); with line(); in processing

Tags: line, processing, fill

Trying to figure out if I can fill in a closed path with color, can this be done?

Here's a basic example of what i'm having trouble with.

```
void setup() {
size(640, 360);

    fill(122,161,158);
    strokeWeight(1);
    stroke(0,0,0);
    line(548,144,516,220);
    line(516,220,599,257);
    line(599,257,548,144);
}
```

The fill doesn't seem to be working. Does fill only work on predefined shapes like rect()? If so is there a way to fill in closed lines.
I'm using processing 2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Please look into [beginShape()](https://processing.org/reference/beginShape_.html):

```
void setup() {
size(640, 360);

    fill(122,161,158);
    strokeWeight(1);
    stroke(0,0,0);
    beginShape();
    vertex(548,144);vertex(516,220);
    vertex(516,220);vertex(599,257);
    vertex(599,257);vertex(548,144);
    endShape();
}
```

Additionally check out [createShape()](https://processing.org/reference/createShape_.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `line()` function does just that: it draws a single line. Processing has no concept of areas defined using this function.

Instead, you want to use the [shape functions](https://processing.org/reference/beginShape_.html). Here's one way you might do it:

```
void setup() {
   size(640, 360);

   fill(122,161,158);
   strokeWeight(1);
   stroke(0,0,0);

   beginShape();
   vertex(548,144);
   vertex(516,220);
   vertex(599);
   vertex(30, 75);
   endShape(CLOSE);
}
```